# Datatable Row Items selection

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to get a particular row (entire column) values in the datatable, and how to redirect these values to the next page?

Comment: you are using dataTable Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a HTML table, you can get all the cell data of a column, as an array, like this:

```
var col = $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(n)").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Where n is the index of the column you want.

To send them to another page, you can encode them and redirect:

```
window.location.href = '/foo.html?data=' + encodeURI(col.join('some-separator'));
```